# How do I make commands in a java game?

Tags: java

Basically I want to make it so when the user types into the textfield /attack animal it does the attack method and takes animal as a parameter. So if player typed /attack foo it do player.attack(foo). I already have methods that perform chat so I know which player is doing the chat. I just need to know how to reconize what comes after the /attack and take it as a parameter for player.attack() which takes a Player object as an argument. These are my methods that receive input:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent textBox) {
        String text = textField.getText();
        player.chat(text);
}
```

Which is in my Gui class, and:

```
public void chat(String chat){
    playerGui.printText(this.getName() + ": " + chat);
    playerGui.textField.selectAll();
}
```

Which is in the player class. A gui instance is passed to Player() which creates the variable playerGui.

Comment: Do you have any code written?  What is your method of receiving input?

Comment: A common approach is to use the chat field for commands. If you start with a `/` then you pass the line to the command interpreter. Consider the mIRC client. If you're in a channel and you put `hello` it's the same as if you put `/say hello`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to tweak this to fit the syntax you want the user to use, but you would probably want to change your actionPerformed method to check for the different actions the user can perform, rather than just chatting.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent textBox) { 
    String text = textField.getText();
    String command = text.substring(0, text.indexOf(" "));
    String args = text.substring(text.indexOf(" ") + 1);
    switch (command) {
        case "chat":
            // Pass everything but the command
            player.chat(args);
            break;
        case "/attack":
            player.attack(args);
            break;
        default:
            // Handle bad user input
    }
}
```

You will still have to verify that you are getting the right kind of arguments for each command, and I didn't put in anything safeguard against null pointers or out-of-bounds with the string functions, but hopefully that will get you started.

Comment: Just reread where you said attack() takes a player as an argument. You would just need to convert the args string to a player in the case before you called the method, or change attack() to take a string and convert it to a player in the attack() method.  If you make all your action methods take strings as parameters, you can keep your actionPerformed method much cleaner.

Comment: it's yelling at me and telling me that it can't take a string and a switch statement: Cannot switch on a value of type String. Only convertible int values or enum constants are permitted

Comment: +1 I think our answers work well together since you handled the command logic and I discussed `Player` lookup. I would make sure the OP's using Java 7 for the `String` switch though - Edit: looks like that's a no.

Comment: The map @kublai khan suggested is a good idea too. And I think he is right about why you can't get switch to work. You can always use a bunch of if, else statements though.

Comment: What's OP? I have Java 7 btw but Eclipse uses the Java 6 compiler i think.

Answer (score 3):

`"/attack arg1 arg2 arg3".split("\\s+")` will give you an array equivalent to `new String[]{"/attack", "arg1", "arg2", "arg3"}` which you can then use for whatever you want.

For invoking it you can reflect into the object (see [Class.getMethod](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%5b%5d%29) for more details on that) if you really need to, but you're probably better off avoiding that if you can.

Comment: I'm a bit of a noob. How would I then use attack(arg1)?

Comment: Going by what @Kublai-Khan said: Assume a `Map<String, Player> players;`, and the current player is `player`, then `String[] command = chat.split("\\s+"); if (command[0].equals("/attack")) { player.attack(players.get(command[1])); }` ... Or go with what @Windle said.

Answer (score 1):

Every instance of your `Player` object should have its own name, a `String` that uniquely identifies it. Store each enemy `Player` in a `Map<String, Player>`, then use this to look up the intended target after parsing its name from the input (which [@mange](https://stackoverflow.com/users/799621/mange) explained how to do).

The `Player` class:

```
public class Player {

   public final String name;

   public Player(String uniqueName) {
      name = uniqueName;
   }

   //additional code
}
```

In a class that makes sense, declare and initialize a `Map` to look up `Player`s from:

```
private static Map<String, Player> players = new HashMap<String, Player>();
```

Throughout the game, when a `Player` is introduced, add it to the `Map`:

```
Player newPlayer = new Player(someUniqueName);
players.put(someUniqueName, newPlayer);
```

When an attack command is given, parse the names and use them to look up each attacked `Player`:

```
public void attackNamedPlayers(String[] names) {
   for (String name : names) {
      Player attackedPlayer = players.get(name); //look up enemy Player by name
      myPlayer.attack(attackedPlayer);           //attack enemy Player
   }
}
```

Don't forget to remove `Player`s from the `Map` when they die/leave:

```
players.remove(deadPlayer.name);
```